# Core Data : What will happen if the previous version of 'xcdatamodel' is missed?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

We're developing an app using Core Data.

First, the app had a file named `MyApp_001.xcdatamodel`, and users have installed it.

Then, we create two branches based on `MyApp_001` : `MyApp_002` & `MyApp_003`.

Now, `MyApp_002` has two model version : `MyApp_001.xcdatamodel` & `MyApp_002.xcdatamodel`, and the current version is `MyApp_002.xcdatamodel`, which has some modification on `MyApp_001.xcdatamodel`.

`MyApp_003` has two model version : `MyApp_001.xcdatamodel` & `MyApp_003.xcdatamodel`, and the current version is `MyApp_003.xcdatamodel`, which also has some modification on `MyApp_001.xcdatamodel`.

What confuses me is : some users have installed `MyApp_002` first,
**Consider that `MyApp_003` doesn't contain the model file `MyApp_002.xcdatamodel`**, when they upgrade the app to `MyApp_003`, there might be some problem?

How Core Data migrates the data indeed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To migrate data to a new model, the old model must be present.**

When migrating a data store from one model to a new model, Core Data needs to be able to open the data store. That means you need the model that the store uses-- either the one that created it or, if you've previously migrated to a new model, the model used in the most recent migration. If that model is not present, migration is impossible.

In your case, if users installing version 3 might be upgrading from version 2, then the version 2 model must be present. It's the only way to open a data store that was created with that model.

**It doesn't matter that a newer model is based on a specific older model.** The fact that version 2 and version 3 are both based on version 1 is completely irrelevant. All that matters for migration is the difference between the current model and the one the data store uses.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you *don't have to migrate the data*. Depending on your case, it may be acceptable to just scrap it.

Comment: I did a test yesterday, and without `MyApp_002.xcdatamodel`, I can upgrade to `MyApp_003` from `MyApp_002`, with the data migration done. Thanks :)